# Swing application slows down on multiple monitor configuration

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm seeing some interesting behaviour on some user's machines with my swing app. I'm wondering if anyone out there has come across similar?

The app is quite memory intensive and we've recently been deploying it with Xms==Xmx==512M

The user machines in question are Windows Xp boxes, 4gb ram, dual-core processors with a single 512M NVidia NVS300 graphics card. They are running multiple monitor setups; one user has 2, the other has 4.

What we've seen is that the app runs fine for a while. Then, for some reason it slows down - the repainting becomes very slow and the app starts churning the cpu.

The thing is; if you drag the screen across to any other monitor then the cpu usage drops and the app starts responding properly again.

I'm guessing that this is memory related, in that it happens when the used heap increases, however I can't explain why. We had previously deployed with -Xms256M and to the best of my knowledge nobody reported this problem when running with that configuration.

Can anyone help explain what might be going on?

Thanks,
Richard

Comment: Users can have multiple frames, but I've seen it happen with just a single frame. It uses Jide docking framwork btw.

Comment: Looks more like a redraw problem than a multi-display problem to me. Are you sure you're not intensively creating objects and never freeing references in your draw methods? Maybe the effect is amplified with more displays... I'd definitely check there, or let it run a few days on a single display machine.

Comment: I think you should check for your callback function. Check all draw methods try to avoid memory allocation and static variables allocation in your callback functions. Same thing you need to check in all your renders. Similar issue I found before some days in our application i.e. if application runs for a longer time then it become slow. You also check these function for heavy calculations and try to optimize calculations in these functions.

Comment: You can use visualVM to check what exactly the problem is you can easily find the memory leaks, thread leaks, Cpu utilization and lot more and can analyzed data when you click on button or open or close any window and lot more. We also able to capture these things using VisualVM. YOu can try it once.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling Direct 3D which is mostly not needed and brought my application a huge performance boost.

-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false

[Disabling 3D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html)